# Python library to make dynamic plots/bar charts with smooth axes/labels update

Tags: python

Which Python libraries would do the job?
The functionalities that I am looking for specifically are for chart animation purposes:

- smooth axes/labels update in plots, bar charts.
- make dynamic graphs
- set background image,change image-shape/size, use flag/symbolic images nearby individual bars in bar chart
- display moving/stationary colorful texts anywhere I like
- read data from csv/json file and apply it to update values in chart
- convert final animation to video format in high quality 2K/4K/HD

I am a newbie to both Python and d3.js. The only reason I am asking is so that I could take some wise advice on which is the best path forward.

It should have intuitive functions be easy to learn.

Comment: [How to ask for an alternative to some software](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software) Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Your only stated reason for seeking an alternative is “`d3.js seems to have a very steep learning curve`” (it doesn’t, but …). It seems likely that any library with equivalent functionality would have an equally steep learning curve, and it would only be worse with a combination of libraries. Personally, I find that D3Js has lots of good examples and good documentation (but YKmMV). Perhaps you are willing to forego some features in order to reduce functionality? If so, you can name them, and ask for something like D3JS, but without x, y & z. Or list only the features that you do want -->

Comment: --> Either way, if you update your question, it will be un-held & should find an answer, as this sort of question is quite common here (see also older questions). Btw, you can get some very good books about D3Js. I bought D3Js for AngularJs, but go the previous edition cheaply from eBay and still found it to be very useful.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the description.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul that looks good enough to un-hold now?

Comment: Also, upvote from me, for making this a good question

Comment: There were still two problems: Asking for an alternative to X (removed), Asking for something that does like <link> (removed). Please check the edited question and explain in better details what you actually need.

Comment: Hi @NicolasRaoul thank you, i updated and specified more functionalities that I'm looking for. But why would asking for alternative to X be a problem? Why would asking for something that does like <link> be a problem , as well? Aren't those the very basic stuffs that happen with asking for software recommendations?

Comment: @Dimanjan: Please read https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software again, and post an answer there if your opinion differs. Cheers!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I have written how my opinion differs. Cheers! https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2844/49674

Comment: @NicolasRaoul please let's not be so tough on the new guy. I have seen much worse questions than this left open and answered.

Comment: @Mawg: The question is OK now that I have edited it (please check the history for the background of the comments).